# Css3 media rule(margin changes) on bootstrap responsive image doesn't work. Why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I would like to change the margin of one image on my site when the screen size is under 300px.
However, my code doesn't seem to work when I resize the window. This works with the same windows size:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1, yet my code does not:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
        </div>
```

css:

```
#logo {
margin-top: -25px;
margin-left: 50px;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #logo {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

what did I mess up? I'm still a novice, especially when it comes to media queries.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, your other CSS is overwriting bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have written @media query for screen less than 300 resolution so it will reflect when screen goes 300 or less than 300.

[find fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5gkbm9br/)

try putting media queries higher like:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #logo {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
   }
 }
```

[image: this is image when I resize fiddle 300 or less then 300 your media queries call]

Comment: Thank you I forgot to tell in my post, that I resized my window. I use this as "control":
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

Answer (score 0):

Remember HTML reads top to bottom, in your *includes* in your HTML page header do you make sure to include *your custom CSS **after** you include the Bootstrap CSS*.  Its just a guess because I can't see the top of your code, but generally when you have some CSS styling that isn't working, thats the problem.  HTML cascades down when it renders, so if **bootstrap.css** is included AFTER yours, all of the *Bootstrap* customizations will override yours.  If you include yours second, then your *customStyles.css* will override the Bootstrap.css elements you need.

Comment: Its a full site with custom css, all the other lines of css works except this. The #logo's margin works too, but it does not reset to 0 when its resized(the media part)

Comment: The fiddle posted by the guy above works for me, so I'm not really sure.  Yours doesn't work is what you're saying?  Worse comes to worse if the margin isn't working try padding, if that doesnt work try `position: relative` and then `left: -__px`.  To be honest I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking...sorry guy :/.  I'll do what I can to help though.